# access a UIButton within a rightBarButtonItem

Tags: swift

I have a navigationcontroller with a right UIBarButtonItem. I have added a UIButton to the BarButtonItem.

How can I get to the button at run time, if possible without using tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myButton:UIButton?

var rightButton = navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems?.first
for view in rightButton.subviews() {
    if view.iskindOfClass(UIButton) {
        myButton = view
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: The first item is a UIButton. No matter what/how I am trying to get it and cast ti UIButton it fails.

Comment: You can't put a UIButton in UINavigationBar, only UIBarButtonItems.

Comment: strongly disagree. You add the bar button item. you then add a button to it. It is just a view within a view...even more the 'rightBarButtonItems is just an AnyObject array.

Comment: In that case, get the UIBarButtonItem as is, then iterate its subviews and check if it is a UIButton.

Comment: this is what is failing. I guess although I only added one item, perhaps swift 'breaks' it into several items. Hence cast 'first' fails.

Comment: I have edited my answer so that the code can now find the UIButton.